# PANDAS ¿Como contar ascendentemente los valores de una columna?

Tags: mysql, python, sql, pandas, stata

Tengo una DF asi

| ACC |
| --- |
| X |
| X |
| Y |
| Y |
| Y |
| Y |
| Z |
| Z |

y quiero crear otra columna que cuenta ascendetemente los valores de ['ACC']
para obtener algo asi:

| ACC | CONTEO |
| --- | --- |
| X | 1 |
| X | 2 |
| Y | 1 |
| Y | 2 |
| Y | 3 |
| Y | 4 |
| Z | 1 |
| Z | 2 |

como lo harian en pandas?

GRACIAS A TODOS

Comment: Sería bueno que mostraras algún código que hayas hecho para guiarte ahí, sino difícil que alguien haga la tarea por ti

Comment: agrega lo que intentaste, de esa manera conseguiras ayuda.

Comment: Los valores iguales siempre te salen agrupados? O podría suceder que haya dos X, luego cuatro Y, luego otra vez varias X? Y en este segundo caso, el segundo grupo de X debería continuar la cuenta donde la dejó el anterior, o empezar de nuevo a numerarse desde 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma simple:

```
df["contador"] = 1
df["contador"] = df.groupby("ACC").cumsum()
```

Resultado:

```
  ACC  contador
0   X         1
1   X         2
2   Y         1
3   Y         2
4   Y         3
5   Y         4
6   Z         1
7   Z         2
```

### Como funciona

Primero, al hacer `df["contador"] = 1`, se crea la columna "contador" y se rellena toda con unos.

Después, `df.groupby("ACC").cumsum()` crea grupos a partir de los valores de la columna "ACC", juntando en un mismo grupo todas las filas que tengan la misma letra. Al aplicar `cumsum()` sobre cada grupo se obtiene la *suma acumulada* dentro de cada grupo. Ya que la única columna sumable es "contador", esa será la que se sume. Ya que estaba inicializada con todo 1, al ir sumando éstos acumulativamente van saliendo los contadores que quieres.

Al asignar el resultado de nuevo a la columna "contador" se cambian los 1 que había allí inicialmente por el resultado de la operación antes descrita.

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió mucho.

Comment: Si consideras que esto resuelve tu pregunta, marca la respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que deberías hacer es poner el código de tu solución, para poder entender cual es tu error o qué estás intentando.
Ahora a tu problema, si estás usando pandas, utiliza una asignación con la columna que quieres al índice de la fila, de esta manera: (index +1 es para que comience en uno y no en 0)

```
df["CONTEO"] = df.index+1
```

Esta funcionalidad está bien si los datos están agrupados, si no lo estuvieran, tienes que comprobar por posiciones. Una posible solución sería sacar los datos de una columna en una serie y recorrerla. Yo he creado una función que comprueba si el anterior es igual o no:

```
def new_column():
 serie= df["ACC"]
 p = []
 serie_recorrer = serie.values
 acumulador = 1
  for index, x in enumerate(serie_recorrer):
   if index == 0:
    p.append(acumulador)
   else:
     if x == serie_recorrer[index-1]:
       acumulador = acumulador + 1
       p.append(acumulador)
     else:
       variable = 1
       p.append(acumulador)

 df["CONTEO"] = pd.DataFrame(p, columns=["a"])

new_column()
```

Comment: Pero no es esto lo que está preguntando. Fíjate que en su ejemplo la columna "conteo" empieza de nuevo en 1 cuando encuentra una letra nueva en la columna "ACC"

Comment: Cierto, no me he fijado en eso, perdón...Edito para poner una posible solución, leí mal...